# finding list of minimum items in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

i have a vector example vector  myVec;

my vector for instance has 100 elements in it. Now I want to iterate through 100 elements and find the possible 10 smallest elements in the vector.

//One way of doing it is to sort the vector items in accending order using sort algoritm and getting the top 10 items. then again here i have to create another vector to store the original and sorted vector. The original program here needs to know the row number of each 10 of the sortest value in the vector - thats in my program.

But now i need a simplest for loop or while statement to find the 10 smallest value in the vector without sorting?.

Comment: `std::partial_sort` is enough over `std::sort`.

Comment: Is this a homework? What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: Row number? You mean the index?

Comment: Does the order of the top (smallest) 10 elements matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I do recommend you use the std library sort, partial_sort, nth_element, etc.  as suggested in the other answers.

However, it is not difficult to find a min, and avoid sort and avoid duplicating the vector,

AND

in case you really mean it when you asked for:

> i need a simplest for loop or while statement to find the 10
>   smallest value in the vector without sorting?.

Here is one approach:  (See comment "find 10 smallest values" below)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>  // shuffle

  typedef std::vector< int >     IntVec;
  typedef std::vector< size_t >  IndxVec;

  const size_t SMALLEST_10 = 10;

  void myVecShow(IntVec& intVec, const std::string label); // below


  // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  size_t findIndxOfMinValue(const IntVec& intVec)
  {
     size_t minIndx = 0; // search from beginning

     for (size_t j = 0;
          j < intVec.size();  // compare each
          ++j)
     {
        if(intVec[j] < intVec[minIndx])
           minIndx = j; // capture smallest
     }
     return(minIndx);
  }


  // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  int t258()
  {
     IntVec myVec;

     {
        // fill myVec
        for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
           myVec.push_back(100-i);    // "my vector for instance has 100 elements in it."

        //myVecShow(myVec, "\n unshuffled values: ");

        // shuffle myVec
        time_t seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::shuffle (myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));

        myVecShow(myVec, "\n Values: ");
     }

     IndxVec indxVec; // to be filled with index of the smallest elements
     indxVec.reserve(SMALLEST_10);

     IntVec  origVal; // capture original values of smallest elements
     origVal.reserve(SMALLEST_10);

     // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     // find 10 smallest values
     {
        for (size_t i=0; i<SMALLEST_10; ++i)
        {
           size_t minValIndx = findIndxOfMinValue(myVec);
           indxVec.push_back (minValIndx);         // capture index
           origVal.push_back (myVec[minValIndx]);  // capture value at index
           myVec[minValIndx] = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // mark min value (so its no longer min)
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
     }

     // restore original values prior to report
     for (size_t i=0; i<indxVec.size(); ++i)
     {
        size_t indx = indxVec[i];
        myVec [indx] = origVal[i];
     }

     // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     // report results
     std::cout << "\nSmallest 10 elements: " << std::endl;
     std::cout << "     indx   value" << std::endl;
     for (size_t i=0; i<indxVec.size(); ++i)
     {
        size_t indx = indxVec[i];
        std::cout << "myVec[" << std::setw(2) << indx
                  << "] = "   << std::setw(3) << myVec[indx]
                  << std::endl;;
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;

     return(0);

  } // int t258(void)


  // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  void myVecShow(IntVec& intVec, const std::string label)
  {
     std::cout << label << std::endl;
     size_t j = intVec.size() - 1;

     // header:
     {
        std::cout << "      ";
        for (size_t i=0; i<SMALLEST_10;  ++i) std::cout << std::setw(3) << i << "   ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
     }

     std::cout << std::setw(3) << 0 << ":  ";

     for (size_t i=0; i<intVec.size(); ++i)
     {
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << intVec[i] << "   ";

        if ((i < j) && (9 == (i % 10)))
        {
           size_t row = 1 + (i / 10);
           std::cout << std::endl << std::setw(3) << row << ":  ";
        }
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;
  }
```

Results: (randomized shuffle)

```
  Values: 
        0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   
  0:   50    85     6    62    48    34    40    73    86    11   
  1:   94    58    46    96    66    56    42    15    25    13   
  2:   92    30     7    35    65    37     5    69    90    68   
  3:  100     3     2    87    21    93    43    99    10    98   
  4:   44    24    70    41    59    95    72    49    78    81   
  5:    4    23    47    51    36    54    12    67    91    14   
  6:   53    97    71    52    77    27    20    29    76    83   
  7:   80    28    17    38    32    16    39     9    74    18   
  8:   84    31    61    45     8    33    82    55    63    89   
  9:   60    26    88    79     1    19    57    75    64    22   


Smallest 10 elements: 
     indx   value
myVec[94] =   1
myVec[32] =   2
myVec[31] =   3
myVec[50] =   4
myVec[26] =   5
myVec[ 2] =   6
myVec[22] =   7
myVec[84] =   8
myVec[77] =   9
myVec[38] =  10
```

---

update - what happens when a value in the smallest 10 is duplicated:

I added

```
myVec[6] = 7;
```

re-ran the code (so, this is a different random shuffle), output is:

```
Smallest 10 elements: 
     indx   value
myVec[ 7] =   0
myVec[78] =   1
myVec[83] =   2
myVec[79] =   3
myVec[11] =   4
myVec[87] =   5
myVec[12] =   7
myVec[67] =   7
myVec[42] =   8
myVec[51] =   9
```

---

update - how might we modify this code to reveal the index's of the smallest 10 **unique** values

Note: not run tested, and this 1st attempt code (probably) does not correctly handle the 100 element array with less than 10 unique values

```
 // find 10 smallest **unique** values
 {
    for (size_t i=0; i<SMALLEST_10; ++i)
    {
       size_t minValIndx = findIndxOfMinValue(myVec);
       indxVec.push_back (minValIndx);         // capture index
       origVal.push_back (myVec[minValIndx]);  
       myVec[minValIndx] = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); 

       // now hide any duplicate of this minValue, 
       for (size_t j=0; j<myVec.size(); ++j)  // search all
       {
          if(myVec[j] == origVal.back()) 
          {
             indxVec.push_back (j);    // capture index
             origVal.push_back (myVec[j]); 
             myVec[minValIndx] = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); 
          }
       }   
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: what if there are two similar integers in this vector.. for example two 10

Comment: @Snowman888 - Is there something special you want to have happen?  When 2 elements (of the smallest 10) have same value, the lower index of that min is found first and reported first (the second element is reported next).

Comment: i was thinking of the same idea. I was trying to know if there were any other shorter route to this problem. What I did was, iterated through the whole vector found the minimum value then increased the value of the minimum element and again iterated till the vector size reached 10.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
// partial_sort example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::partial_sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  int myints[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+9);

  // using default comparison (operator <):
  std::partial_sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+5, myvector.end());

  // print out content:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
myvector contains: 1 2 3 4 5 9 8 7 6
```

It uses [std::partial_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/) (as Jarod42 said), which sorts the first `n` values (the 10 in your case), while leaving the other values in any order. Now you can sure modify that to meed your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, given that you only need to know the 10 smallest items (and don't need those ten in order) you can use `std::nth_element` instead of `std::partial_sort`. This does precisely what you've asked for with nothing extra, so it stands a good chance of being more efficient.

As far as avoiding copying your input, you could create a vector of indices that you use to index into the original array, and operate on the index instead of the original array.

The general idea would look something like this:

```
std::vector<foo> input;

// ...

// This is our index. It'll be filled with 0..I (where I = size of input).
std::vector<std::size_t> index(input.size());
std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

// This is the number of smallest items we need to find:
const int N = 10;


if (index.size() <= N) // if we have fewer elements, do nothing.
    return;

// sort our index according to the values in the input:
std::nth_element(index.begin(), index.begin() + N, index.end(),
    [&input](size_t a, size_t b) { return input[a] < input[b]; });

// write out the N smallest items of the input.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    std::cout << input[index[i]] << "\t";
```

You could, of course, use a vector of pointers to the original items instead of indices, but you said you needed the "row numbers", so I wrote the code to provide exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to code this yourself, use quick select to find the 10th smallest element. This will separate the array into parts, the left with smallest to 9th smallest on the left but not sorted, the 10th smallest as the pivot, and the right with elements >= 10th smallest element. Wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect